# Stern's sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Summing the cubes of the insertion sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/summing-the-cubes-of-the-insertion-sequence)

Could anyone help me determine the sum of cube of elements of the Stern's sequence?

Here is some information about it: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/layman/sequences/ins_seq.htm

Thank you very much