# Sum of cubes in a sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stern's sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83187/sterns-sequence)
>   [Summing the cubes of the insertion sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88238/summing-the-cubes-of-the-insertion-sequence)

Having a finite sequence of numbers given, we create a new sequence by inputting in each step between every pair of two adjacent numbers a new number equal to their sum. We start with (1,1), in the second step we have (1,2,1), in the third (1,3,2,3,1) etc. For every $n\geq1$ calculate the sum of the cubes of the numbers being part of the sequence acquired in the nth step.

What we know is that in every step, for a sequence of lenght n we'll get n-1 new numbers being the sums of the adjacents so the next sequence will be 2n-1. The sum of the first is $1^3+1^3=2$, then we have $1^{3}+2^{3}+1^{3}=2+8=10$, then the_sum_so_far+$2*3^{3}$. The useful property is that the sequence is symmetrical having some k pairs of numbers on both sides of the central 2 and always has an odd amount of numbers - only the first step is even. How does that lead to a solution, though? Could you please help?